# How do I bind an event when using Turbolinks?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I want to stop a form from posting if it's text area is blank. I'm using jQuery and Turbolinks. I have to bind on `ajax:beforeSend`, but I get it to work:

```
  $(document).on 'page:load', '.task-form', ->
    $(this).bind 'ajax:beforeSend', ->
      alert "hi"
```

I see no alert when submitting the form. Any idea why?

I'm loading the form remotely via ajax.

```
# tasks/new.js.erb
$('.task-form-wrapper').append('<%= j render("form") %>');
$('#task_name').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on 'page:load', '.task-form', ->
```

The `page:load` event is not triggered on the `.task-form` element, it's triggered on the `document`. You'll have to change it to:

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  $('.task-form').on 'ajax:beforeSend', ->
    alert 'hi'
```

I changed `page:load` to `page:change` otherwise it only works if the first page request is on the view with the form. `page:change` is triggered every time a new page is loaded.